# Update NSMutableArray after adding New object

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I have a `NSMutableArray` which contains some `NSMutableDictionary` object type. In some situations I have to add one field to each `NSMutableDictionary` inside this Array, but I don't know how?

I do add object (field) into my `NSMutableDictionary` like this.

```
NSMutableDictionary *item = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:[timeSlots objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

[item setObject:cell forKey:@"cell"];
```

Now how am I going to update the Array (timeSlots)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add this line after changing the mutable dictionary:

```
[timeSlots replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:item];
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs of course, but this would be a starting point:

```
for (NSMutableDictionary *aDictionary in array) {
    [aDictionary setObject:cell forKey:@"cell"];
}
```